# can't play this video error on android app

Tags: android, android-layout

when you put any video link in android studio it simply shoe "can't play this video error"

this my code-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView view=findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        view.setVideoPath("android.resource//"+getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.demo);
        MediaController control=new MediaController(this);
        control.setAnchorView(view);
        view.setMediaController(control);
        view.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the video is encoded with android-supported codec, and is stored in a supported format?

Comment: also try creating URI from resource instead of using `setVideoPath`

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demo);

mc = new MediaController(this);
vd.setMediaController(mc);

vd.setVideoURI(uri);
vd.start();
```

you need to convert into Uri try below code and share your feedback or share the error log if any

Comment: its working for me, can you please share the error log or copy below code: 
VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demo);

mc = new MediaController(this);
vd.setMediaController(mc);

vd.setVideoURI(uri);
vd.start();

Comment: Thank you very much ,sir...now its working properly.